# Search value in object of various data in Javascript recursivly

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion, search

Good day everyone! I have a problem with a search function on JavaScript.

This is an object I have (states):

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Category #1",
        "hasChild": "Y",
        "count": "0",
        "parentId": null,
        "link": "/catalog/",
        "subcategories": [
            {
                "id": "21",
                "name": "Subcategory #1",
                "hasChild": "Y",
                "count": "0",
                "parentId": "1",
                "link": "/catalog/",
                "subcategories": [
                    {
                        "id": "24",
                        "name": "subsubcategory #1",
                        "hasChild": "Y",
                        "count": "1",
                        "parentId": "21",
                        "link": "/catalog/",
                        "subcategories": [],
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "25",
                        "name": "subsubcategory #2",
                        "hasChild": "Y",
                        "count": "0",
                        "parentId": "21",
                        "link": "/catalog/",
                        "subcategories": [],
                    }
                ],
            },
            {
                "id": "22",
                "name": "Subcategory #2",
                "hasChild": "Y",
                "count": "0",
                "parentId": "1",
                "link": "/catalog/",
            },
            {
                "id": "23",
                "name": "Subcategory #3",
                "hasChild": "Y",
                "count": "0",
                "parentId": "1",
                "link": "/catalog/",
            }
        ],
    },
    "2": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Category #2",
        "hasChild": "Y",
        "count": "0",
        "parentId": null,
        "link": "/catalog/",
        "subcategories": [
            ..
        ],
    },

}
```

And I have an array of products to which one has an **id of the category** to which it belongs. So I extracted from there only unique values of categories. It can be any level.

```
["24", "22", "2" ...]
```

My goal is to take the "name" values of parents' categories.

Example: product is in a category with id:24 (name: subsubcategory #1).

**How can I get the value "Category #1" from the top category?**

I use that function, but it only work for me on 1-st level (if id:1 or 2)

```
function filter(item, search, textKey) {
                let result = []
                const _filter = (item, search, textKey) => {
                    for (const i of item) {
                        if (i[textKey].indexOf(search) !== -1) {
                            result = [...result, { name: i.name, id: i.id, parentId: i.parentId }]
                        }
                        i.children ? _filter(i.children, search, textKey) : null
                    }
                }
                _filter(item, search, textKey)
                return result
            }
```

```
console.log(filter(Object.values(states), '24', 'id')) // didn't work
console.log(filter(Object.values(states), '2', 'id')) // found and mapped
```

Comment: The shell of your object looks strange.  Are you sure you don't have an array at the top level?  An object with keys corresponding to low-valued integers looks like it might be an artifact of console output.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, that object looks strange to me too, but that's what I got from the backend. I think removing keys from it (on the top level) would be the right decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build a function that finds the names associated with a list of ids by mapping over a function that finds the names associated with a single id.  That I would build atop a function which recursively finds the full ancestor node based on an arbitrary predicate.

Your initial input is not quite a recursive structure.  It looks like it might be a bad copy from console output, although it could still be legitimate.  In any case, we do a transformation first, using `Object .values` to extract an array of actual category nodes.  This could be moved from one level of the call chain to another, depending on what level of reuse you want from these functions.  If your data is in fact an array, this will still work, but I would suggest replacing `Object .values (states)` with just `states`, as it makes for cleaner code.

```js
const rootAncestor = (pred) => (xs) => 
  xs .find (x => pred (x) || rootAncestor (pred) (x .subcategories || []))

const rootAncestorName = (states) => (id) => 
  rootAncestor (x => x .id == id) (states) ?.name ?? ''

const rootAncestorNames = (states) => (ids) =>
  ids .map (rootAncestorName (Object .values (states)))

const states = {1: {id: "1", name: "Category #1", hasChild: "Y", count: "0", parentId: null, link: "/catalog/", subcategories: [{id: "21", name: "Subcategory #1", hasChild: "Y", count: "0", parentId: "1", link: "/catalog/", subcategories: [{id: "24", name: "subsubcategory #1", hasChild: "Y", count: "1", parentId: "21", link: "/catalog/", subcategories: []}, {id: "25", name: "subsubcategory #2", hasChild: "Y", count: "0", parentId: "21", link: "/catalog/", subcategories: []}]}, {id: "22", name: "Subcategory #2", hasChild: "Y", count: "0", parentId: "1", link: "/catalog/"}, {id: "23", name: "Subcategory #3", hasChild: "Y", count: "0", parentId: "1", link: "/catalog/"}]}, 2: {id: "2", name: "Category #2", hasChild: "Y", count: "0", parentId: null, link: "/catalog/", subcategories: []}}

console .log (rootAncestorNames (states) (['24', '22', '2', '42']))
```

I added a failing lookup with `42` to show that I make the guess that we want to return an empty string.  But at the end of `rootAncestorName`, you could replace that with `null`, `undefined`, or some other token.